# THis is what I got UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, hex

this is the code I received from some bad API on python 3.5
`b'{"code":67,"message":"\xe7\xa7\x81\xe9\x92\xa5\xe9\xaa\x8c\xe8\xaf\x81\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe8\xb4\xa5 ","msg":"\xe7\xa7\x81\xe9\x92\xa5\xe9\xaa\x8c\xe8\xaf\x81\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe8\xb4\xa5 "}'`
I wish to convert them to JSON. but I cannot.
It is byted JSON but the string part is hex (chinese), so I cannot use decode() or replace() or binascii.b2a_hex(), binascii.a2b_hex()
replace them is extremely hard too, they are not string nor int
I spend about 5 hours on this. I am new to python but have 3 years of coding experience.

Comment: You cannot use decode()? What encoding did you try to decode with?

Comment: That is not valid JSON (it uses the wrong format of hex escape).

Comment: To be clear: What did you _specifically_ try? What caused the exception given in the title? Why do you think the various functions you listed are not useful for you? This question is off-topic since it does not have a bit of code in it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(b'{"code":67,"message":"\xe7\xa7\x81\xe9\x92\xa5\xe9\xaa\x8c\xe8\xaf\x81\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe8\xb4\xa5 ","msg":"\xe7\xa7\x81\xe9\x92\xa5\xe9\xaa\x8c\xe8\xaf\x81\xe5\xa4\xb1\xe8\xb4\xa5 "}')
{'code': 67, 'message': '私钥验证失败 ', 'msg': '私钥验证失败 '}
```

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'